# Show every ideal in the maximal order of a quadratic number field is proper

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I was working in David Cox's *Primes of the Form $x^2 + ny^2$*, and am currently stuck on this question:

> Let $K$ be a quadratic number field and $\mathcal{O}_K$ its ring of integers. An $\mathcal{O}_K$-ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ is said to be proper if the set $\{\beta \in K : \beta \mathfrak{a} \subset \mathfrak{a}\} = \mathcal{O}_K$.
>   Show that every ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ is proper.

I figure I will have to make use of the fact that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is the maximal order, or possibly the fact that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a Dedekind domain, but am not quite sure how the argument will go. Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I should mention that the containment $\supset$ is immediate because $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$, then
$\{\beta \in K : \beta \mathfrak{a} \subseteq \mathfrak{a}\}$
is an order that contains $\mathcal{O}_K$. Now if $\mathcal{O}_K$
is the maximal order...

Comment: Oh, it was right in front of me the whole time! Thank you!